# On which device do I install the bootloader when I want to dual boot?

Tags: dual-boot, kubuntu, 15.04, windows-8, bootloader

I'm currently trying to install Kubuntu 15.04 alongside Windows 8.1 (already installed).
It's on a non-UEFI machine.

My partitions are as follows:

- sda1 windows installation (500GB SSD)
- sdb1 HDD just for data (1.9TB)
- sdb2 very small partition that was already there don't know what it
  does (367MB)
- sdb3 the partition I created for Kubuntu (100GB)

Now in the installation menu of Kubuntu where I do the partitioning and so on I also have to choose which device the boot loader gets installed on. Which one do I choose for that?

sda1 where my windows installation is or sdb3 where my Kubuntu installation will be?

The bootloader is for choosing which OS I want to boot in later right? But I have no idea where I have to install it.

Edit: [This is what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2wQa.jpg)

Comment: I see no EFI boot partitions, so I assume this is a non-UEFI machine.  Can it boot from either disk?  Is the second disk removable?

Comment: With BIOS & MBR, better to have grub in MBR of Ubuntu drive (sdb in your case) and keep Windows boot loader in MBR of Windows drive. And set BIOS to boot from Ubuntu/grub drive. If ever grub boot issues, you can go into BIOS or one time boot key and still boot Windows. If grub is in Windows drive or sda, then any failure of grub prevents boot of both systems. Either way best to have both Windows repairCD or Ubuntu live DVD or flash drives with each. Then you can always boot something to make repairs.

Comment: Do you know which one is set to be the master drive (via hardware(!) setting)?

Comment: @oldfred: So do I install the bootloader to sdb and not sdb3? And this will be no problem with sdb being partly NTFS and ext4? What happens if I would upgrade my  Windows 8.1 installation to Windows 10 in a few days?

Comment: BIOS based systems only boot from MBR, not from a PBR or partition boot sector. Generally best to never install grub to PBR as it does not really fit and will complain about using blocklists or hard coded addresses. IF you reinstall Windows it will auto overwrite MBR, and you have to restore grub to MBR again. But When you update Windows it is vitial on which drive is set as boot in BIOS. As Windows will update boot files & MBR on that drive. Windows normally only had boot files on one drive that is bootable in BIOS and in primary NTFS partition with boot flag.

Answer (score 1):

You want to run this in Terminal:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

Then tell your BIOS to boot off the first hard disk.

Comment: I don't have Kubuntu installed yet. I'm still stuck in the Installation menu of it.

Comment: Ah.  You want to install GRUB (the bootloader) on /dev/sda, and that should take care of it.